# Calculation giving wrong result while i format the values with number_format in php

Tags: php

```
 $MarketValue  = number_format(100000 * 4, 2, '.',',');
 $purchasing_val =number_format(100000 * 6, 2, '.',',');
 $pls   = $purchasing_val - $MarketValue  ;
```

The Above Code result should be 200000 but its just showing 200, its only occur when i format the values, Where's the error ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to format then calculate.
Try to calculate, then format the number.

```
$MarketValue  = 100000 * 4;
$purchasing_val = 100000 * 6;
$pls   = number_format($purchasing_val - $MarketValue, 2, '.', ',');
```

EDIT:
As you asked, in case you want to show them as formatted, you have many options.
You could just echo them as `number_format($purchasing_val, 2, '.', ',');` and `number_format($MarketValue, 2, '.', ',');` 
or you could store them as another variable to show later on like

```
$FormattedMarketValue  = number_format($MarketValue, 2, '.', ',');
$Formattedpurchasing_val = number_format($purchasing_val, 2, '.', ',');
```

And when ever in your script you echo the two variables `$FormattedMarketValue` and `$Formattedpurchasing_val`

Comment: yes, but i also have to show the values in format form somewhere in my script.

Comment: If you want to show your values as formatted, just show them formatted within an echo or something, but you can't calculate them while formatted, they are supposed to be integers, and when formatting them and calculating, php won't consider the "," a part of the number, it will only take the part before it. I'll edit my post.